# javascript date String array push issue! Not the desired value

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'd like to get a date between the start and end dates

```
  d = 'Tue Oct 2 00:00:00 UTC+0900 2018';
  date2 = 'Fri Oct 5 00:00:00 UTC+0900 2018';

  var arrTemp = new Array();
  //var dispalyHTML = '';

while(d <= date2){
  //dispalyHTML += d.yyyymmdd();
  var date_yy = d.getFullYear();
  var date_mm = (d.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0' +(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1);
  var date_dd = d.getDate() <10 > '0'+d.getDate():d.getDate();

  alert("date_yy+date_mm+date_dd=="+date_yy+date_mm+date_dd);

  **arrTemp.push(date_yy+date_mm+date_dd);**
  d = d.addDays(1);
}


for(j=0; j < arrTemp.length; j++){

    alert("arrTemp[j]=="+arrTemp[j]);
 }
```

The first value,
is the desired value. be worth!

```
 date_yy+date_mm+date_dd==20181002
 date_yy+date_mm+date_dd==20181003
 date_yy+date_mm+date_dd==20181004
 date_yy+date_mm+date_dd==20181005
```

BUT arrTemp[j] value, Not the desired value.

```
arrTemp[j]==202802
arrTemp[j]==202803
arrTemp[j]==202804
arrTemp[j]==202805
```

Do you know why?

Comment: `d` and `date2` are strings, so ... `d.yyyymmdd()` is a totally made up function you invented, `d.getFullTear()` is not even a real Date method, it's `getFullYear`,  and all the other Date methods like `d = d.addDays(1);` will fail, because a String is not a Date object, and lexical comparison with a date string isn't going to be at all useful `"Fri" < "Tue"` for example... you should be using Date object - surely you saw errors in the developer tools console? and your code would result in `arrTemp` being empty, because it simply can not run as shown in the question

Comment: TL;DR - please post the *actual* code you're having an issue with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use moment, never try and roll your own date functions.

```js
let date1 = moment('02/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
let date2 = moment('05/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
 
let noOfDays = moment(date2).diff(moment(date1), 'days') + 1;
 
days = (date, noOfDays) => Array.from(Array(noOfDays), (_, i) => moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(i, 'd').format('YYYYMMDD'));
 
console.log(days('02/10/2018', noOfDays));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There were some mistakes in code above which I have corrected. When pushing to an array .toString() should be used otherwise it takes timestamp value. Please try this out.

```
d = new Date('Tue Oct 2 00:00:00 UTC+0900 2018'); 
    date2 = new Date('Fri Oct 5 00:00:00 UTC+0900 2018');

  var arrTemp = [];
  var dispalyHTML = '';

while(d <= date2){
  var date_yy = d.getFullYear();
  var date_mm = (d.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0' +(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1);
  var date_dd = d.getDate() <10 ? '0'+d.getDate():d.getDate();

  alert("date_yy+date_mm+date_dd=="+date_yy+date_mm+date_dd);
  arrTemp.push(date_yy.toString()+date_mm.toString()+date_dd.toString());
  d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
}
for(j=0; j < arrTemp.length; j++){
    alert("arrTemp[j]=="+arrTemp[j]);
 }
```